# how to input more than 2000 characters in text box using JAVA

Tags: java

Is it possible to input more than 2000 characters with a loop in text box. It doesn't matter what the characters are, because I only need to validate text box should allow 2000 characters. I am using java with selenium.

Comment: If that field is text area and your developer did not put any character limit till 2000 then you can input easily.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, [JTextField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html) from swing package doesn't have a limit on characters. You could also use a [JTextArea](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html) too if you require multiline